# ¿trabajar con el icono bars para que funcione el list en modo responsive?

Tags: html, css3, responsive

Una consulta! haber si me pueden ayudar.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de una página web sencilla (soy junior aun :D). En el Index para visualizar en pc cada uno de los elementos del menu llevan a una seccion especifica de la pagina (eso funciona perfectamente).

Sin embargo a la hora de querer trabajar con media query para tratar de hacer responsive la web con pantallas mas pequeñas -tablets/celulares- agregue un icono Bars para que aloje los elementos del menu y los muestre al hacer clic.

Sin embargo no se como hacer para que cuando despliega la lista en responsive me redireccione a las mismas secciones (por que simplemente no me redirecciona por arte de magia) como cuando esta en pantalla normal -PCs-.

Les comparto el codigo que he avanzado del media query.

Espero me haya explicado bien. Saludos!

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  p {
    font-size: 130%;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 150%;
  }
  header {
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
  }
  header #logo {
    margin: 15px 0 20px -25px;
  }

  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  nav ul, nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #a5bdcd;
    right: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    opacity: .90;
  }
   nav li {
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bahá'ís de Nicaragua</title>
        <!--Iconos FontAwesome-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!--Slider Jquery BxSlider-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

   <div id="banner-wrapper">
        <header>
          <div href="#" id="header-inner">
            <a href="index.html" id="logo">
              <img src="img/pics/estrella3.jpg" alt="Logo Bahá'í">
            </a>
            <nav>
              <a href="#" id="menu-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bars "></i>
              </a>
              <ul href="#" id="menu-lista">
                <li>
                  <a href="index.html" class="current">INICIO</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#skills">HABILIDADES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#portfolio">PORTAFOLIO</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#services">SERVICIOS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#contact">CONTACTO</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo esta ocasionando esta regla:

```
nav ul, nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #a5bdcd;
    right: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    opacity: .90;
  }
```

Yo la he dejado así:

```
 nav ul {
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        border: 1px solid #a5bdcd;
        right: 20px;
        width: 25%;
        opacity: .90;
 }
```

Creo que es porque la pseudo clase **:active** hace que cuando hagas click en la etiqueta **nav** la lista desaparece y eso impide que hagas click en los enlaces, piensan que los enlaces estan dentro de la etiqueta **nav**